# Google Big Query using Simba Jdbc Driver gives unknown error, if size is greater than 26 characters is in compare string

Tags: java, jdbc, google-bigquery

We are using simba jdbc driver to connect to Big query from our application. We found that if the query contains IN clause with an & in the values the jdbc driver gives Metadata type error.
Ex query:

```
Select * from my_big_table where channel IN ("LOCAL & TRADITIONAL GROCERY")
```

> com.simba.support.exceptions.GeneralException: Error message not
>   found: METADATA_INCORRECT_TYPE_ERR. Can't find resource for bundle
>   java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key METADATA_INCORRECT_TYPE_ERR     at
>   com.simba.googlebigquery.utils.BQCoreUtils.convertSqlTypeToBigQueryType(Unknown
>   Source) ~[GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar:na]    at
>   com.simba.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.execute(Unknown
>   Source) ~[GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar:na]    at
>   com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown
>   Source) ~[GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar:na]    at
>   com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>   ~[GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.

Is there way to by pass this?

Link to the issue in Big Query Issue tracker: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=928

NOTE: Previously I had said the issue is with having '&' in the value. But on further investigation I found it has nothing to do with & in value but with the length of the value in the IN Clause is equal to or greater than 27

Comment: For future readers, the issue on the public tracker is https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=928.

Comment: Yes. I created it there as well. Putting the link in the question itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug tracked on http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=928, not a programming question.

Comment: The question is not off-topic. It is a programming question as well. I faced it when I was trying to code with simba jdbc driver. The first thing when I faced the issue was search stack overflow. It would hence be incorrect to close this question, for in future some poor programmer like me may come here searching for a solution to this bug.

Comment: I found this with a `LIKE` expression, too.

Comment: We wrote our own JDBCdriver to connect to big query and left simba driver.